# Sql server Query to select result from same table based on diffrent conditions

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2014

I have two tables i.e Measurement and  Clinical.

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE Measurement
(
    [MeasurementID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CHID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MeasureID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InputValue] [varchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [MeasurementDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Clinical
(
    [ClinicalID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CHID] [int],
    [ClientID] [int] NOT NULL
)

insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(111,118,'Yes',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(112,198,'Yes',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(112,82,'Referred to Comm Pres',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(113,118,'Yes',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(114,198,'Yes',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(114,82,'Referred to Comm Pres',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(115,118,'Yes',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(115,198,'No',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(115,82,'Referred to Comm Pres',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(116,118,'Yes',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(116,198,'No',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(116,82,'Univeristy',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(117,188,'Yes',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(117,198,'Yes',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(117,82,'Univeristy',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(200,188,'Yes',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(201,198,'Yes',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(202,82,'Univeristy',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(203,188,'Yes',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(203,198,'Yes',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(205,188,'Yes',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(203,5000,'Yes',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(203,500,'Yes',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(205,1555,'NO',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(207,188,'Yes',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(208,198,'Yes',19-10-2016)
insert into Measurement(CHID,MeasureID,InputValue,MeasurementDate) values(209,82,'Referred to Comm Pres',19-10-2016)

insert into Clinical(CHID,ClientID) values(111,1)
insert into Clinical(CHID,ClientID) values(112,1)
insert into Clinical(CHID,ClientID) values(113,2)
insert into Clinical(CHID,ClientID) values(114,2)
insert into Clinical(CHID,ClientID) values(115,2)
insert into Clinical(CHID,ClientID) values(116,3)
insert into Clinical(CHID,ClientID) values(117,4)
insert into Clinical(CHID,ClientID) values(200,4)
insert into Clinical(CHID,ClientID) values(201,4)
insert into Clinical(CHID,ClientID) values(202,4)
insert into Clinical(CHID,ClientID) values(203,5)
insert into Clinical(CHID,ClientID) values(205,6)

insert into Clinical(CHID,ClientID) values(207,7)
insert into Clinical(CHID,ClientID) values(208,7)
insert into Clinical(CHID,ClientID) values(209,7)
```

I want result as follows:

```
ClientID | InputValue of(188) | InputValue of(198)| InputValue of(82)
----------------------------------------------------------------------    
7        | Yes                | Yes               | Referred to Comm Pres
6        | Yes                | null              | null
5        | yes                | yes               | null
```

**Note**: we should only consider 188,198 which has input value "Yes"
and 82 value should be only 'Referred to Comm Pres'

Anyone can please help me with this. Please comment if you need more clarification.Thank you

i tried the following

```
with Table1 AS
(
   select 
       CH.ClientID, CM.*
   from 
       Measurement CM 
   inner join 
       Clinical CH ON CM.CHID = CH.CHID
   where 
       MeasureID in (188, 198, 82)
) 
select  
    T1.ClientID, T1.MeasurementID, T1.MeasureID, T1.CHID,
    T1.InputValue, T2.InputValue, T3.InputValue, T1.MeasurementDate
from  
    Table1 T1
join 
    Table1 T2 on (T1.ClientID = T2.ClientID) 
join 
    Table1 T3 on (T2.ClientID = T3.ClientID) 
where  
    T2.MeasureID = 198 
    and lower(T2.InputValue) = 'yes'
    and t3.MeasureID = 82 
    and T1.MeasureID = 188 
    and lower(T1.InputValue) = 'yes'
    and T1.ClientID not in (select ClientID 
                            from Table1 
                            where MeasureID = 82 
                              and InputValue not in ('Referred to Comm Pres'))
group by 
    T1.ClientID, T1.MeasurementID, T1.MeasureID, T1.CHID, 
    T1.InputValue, T2.InputValue, T3.InputValue, T1.MeasurementDate 
order by 
    T1.MeasurementDate, T1.MeasurementID, T1.CHID, T1.MeasureID
```

Comment: Please post what you tried so far..

Comment: I added what i have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Try using SQL server PIVOT, as shown below.

```
SELECT  CLIENTID, 
        CASE WHEN [188] = 'YES' THEN [188] ELSE NULL END AS [InputValue of(188)] , 
        CASE WHEN [198] = 'YES' THEN [198] ELSE NULL END AS [InputValue of(198)],
        CASE WHEN [82] = 'Referred to Comm Pres' THEN [82] ELSE NULL END AS [InputValue of(82)]
FROM (
    SELECT B.ClientID,A.MEASUREID,A.InputValue,Row_Number() over(order by clientid) as ID -- Pivot grouping column
    FROM Measurement A
    INNER JOIN Clinical B
    ON A.CHID = B.CHID
    WHERE A.MEASUREID IN (188, 198, 82)
) as s
PIVOT
(
    MIN(InputValue)
    FOR MEASUREID IN ([188], [198], [82])
)AS pvt
```

Comment: The above answer is somewhat working but it is also showing client which has 82 value = 'university' which should not be shown also if there are multiple entries for clients then it should show as separate row

Comment: @adi_2010 I have modified the answer to show all clients as separate rows. I quite does not understand your comment on "university" filter, but I guess that should be trivial and you should be able to alter the query yourself.